# Reference Request: Visual Approach to Symmetric Groups

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, symmetric-groups, visualization, braid-groups

The symmetric group is a factor of the braid group (see e.g. [Surjective Group Homomorphism From Braid Group Into Symmetric Group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1165136/169085), [Symmetric group, Braid Groups, and related groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1816878/169085)). Consequently one can visualize an element in the symmetry group like a braid with no information regarding which strand is on top at a crossing (e.g. as done here: [Symmetric Group $S_n$ and Artin Braid Group $B_n$: Differences in definition of composition?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4074230/169085) or here https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.02533 on p.19). It seems to me rather intuitive, convenient and fast (and more fun) to use "wire symbols" as opposed to the cycle notation (e.g. with wire symbols one need not name the elements being permuted).

---

**Question:** Is there a relatively detailed account of the symmetric group that uses fundamentally these wire symbols, say at the undergraduate (or below) level?

I am aware that the question has ambiguities; any answer to a reasonable interpretation of the question is welcome.

---

Here is a humble demonstration as to what I mean by a "wire symbol":

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "uses fundamentally"? I believe there are many textbooks that use one or a few wire diagrams to show permutations, at least when introducing the symmetric group. But they would usually stick with more compact notations afterward.

Comment: @MarkS. That was one of the ambiguities in my question. One interpretation could be that an account uses wire symbols fundamentally if the account presents them as the primary tool for experimentation as to whether or not a certain statement is true.

Comment: Or for instance the account presents mostly "proofs without (or with a sparing amount of) words"; for instance as a proof for the statement that any cycle is a product of transpositions the decomposition of a cyclic wire symbol into wire symbols each with exactly one cross at an appropriate place is drawn.

Comment: Another way to answer your question is to say that an account uses wire symbols fundamentally if it uses them in a comparable way an introductory account of braid groups uses braid symbols. An introductory account of braid groups can be taken to be an account comparable to the one in https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/braids.html, or Armstrong's book Groups and symmetry.

Comment: I would also humbly suggest that wire symbols are more compact and lower in complexity, compared to the traditional ones.

Comment: "wire symbols are more compact" I can't write them inline like I can with some other notations.